# How to retrieve Mailchimp campaign id using api v3

Tags: php

I'm new to the Mailchimp api v3.0 (using php). I've created a campaign with the api and want to retrieve the campaign id from the cURL return data but can't seem to extract just the id. I've been away from php for awhile so I guess I'm just being brain dead. Clearly, I can print the entire result but just need to extract the campaign id in order to add/update content. Most of the test code follows. How do I extract just the id from $retval?

```
$json_data = json_encode($options);
$auth = base64_encode('prcAdmin:'. $apikey);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://usn.api.mailchimp.com /3.0/campaigns');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content_Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . $auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
$retval = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

A few typos in your code, let's fix them first.

- An extra space in the url
- `Content_Type` to `Content-Type`. Good to correct it, though the endpoint returns data in a JSON format.

Assuming that you have a valid Auth with valid campaign data, it should return campaign data in JSON format. To extract the campaign id is pretty easy.

```
$campaign = json_decode($retval, true);
$campaignId = $campaign['id'];
```

If you can't get correct a campaign id, try to print out the result by using `print_r($retval);`. The correct data should look similar to an example response found on this page - http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/. (From and between curly brackets).

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I corrected the two items and re-ran it.  I added print_r($campaignId); after the assignment to $campaignId.  Unfortunately, I keep getting the entire response; for all the cURL processing. It won't extract just the 'id'.  The 'id' is clearly in the response but it won't extract just it. I've done this kind of thing previously so I'm really confused.

Comment: Also, the print_r($campaignId); result displays: {"id":"be99006c5f","type":"regular","create_time":"....  and lots more data from the result of the curl_exec. The campaign was created and a response was returned. I just can't extract the returned campaign id.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem:  I added a: 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

and it obviously returned the response differently so the "id" tag could be referenced as:
    $id = json_decode($retval);
    echo $id->id;

Now it extracts just the "id".